# django: two-model form not saving

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I followed an [instruction](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2081/) to create a form using User model and Profile model. I think the entered data is successfully uploaded to view function but the data is not saved to database because when I reload the page the data is gone. Do you have any idea to help me out? Thank you.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pic = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path,
                            blank=True,
                            default=static('img/jenny.jpg')
    )
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES,
                              blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username



@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def ensure_profile_exists(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('created', False):
        Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=kwargs.get('instance'))
```

forms.py

```
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'last_name', 'first_name']


class ProfileForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # magic
        self.user = kwargs['instance'].user
        user_kwargs = kwargs.copy()
        user_kwargs['instance'] = self.user
        self.uf = UserForm(*args, **user_kwargs)
        # magic end

        super(ProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields.update(self.uf.fields)
        self.initial.update(self.uf.initial)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.uf.save(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(ProfileForm, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'profiles/update.html'
    form_class = ProfileForm


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):

        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()

        profile = queryset.get(pk=self.request.user.profile.pk)

        return profile
```

Comment: Try to use a separate `CreateView` when adding initial data and `UpdateView` when editing existing data.

Comment: profile is created by `post_save()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I wrote a blog post about it [Extend Django User Model and Generic Class Based View “GCBV”](http://www.emadmokhtar.com/2015/12/extend-django-user-model-gcbv/), sorry I can't write the whole answer here, put you will have the whole code soultion there.

Comment: But your method has to user two forms in template which is not my case. I end up with using two separate pages. Anyway, thank you.